# Elasticsearch "Painless" returns wrong and rounded values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Running Elasticsearch 7.3.2.
I have two float fields "timeEnd" and timeStart. I simply want to return difference.

In Kibana index-patterns I created a scripted variable "rate":

```
if (doc['timeEnd'].length==0) return null;
if (doc['timeStart'].length==0) return null;
return doc['timeEnd'].value-doc['timeStart'].value;
```

This is what it returns:

```
[
 {
  "timeEnd": null,
  "timeStart": 1571760869.518571,
  "rate": [
   null
  ]
 },
 {
  "timeEnd": 1571760898.821922,
  "timeStart": 1571760736.872881,
  "rate": [
   128
  ]
 },
 {
  "timeEnd": 1571760893.483377,
  "timeStart": 1571760879.161604,
  "rate_mbps": [
   0
  ]
 },...
```

Most returned values are 0 or 128.

Comment: I have faced similar problem. The solution is to use 'double' instead of 'float'. Ideally, float should have been able to handle calculation (add/sub) on these values but for some reason it shows problem. Hence, just change the data-type to 'double'

Comment: @Atur thanks I will try that. Are you aware of any bug report? This is a rather serious issue.

Comment: I am not aware of any bug, but I can search for it. This looks like a common case, so there should already be a bug logged.

Comment: @Atur. I checked reindexing to doubles and it works!

Comment: Great! This is definitely a pretty common problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timeEnd and timeStart are of float type , which is a single-precision 32-bit floating point number. You need to change them to double which is a double-precision 64-bit floating point number

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Does it mean I have to change template (dynamically generated) and reindex all the data?

Comment: Yes..reindex will be beneficial/required. Also I would suggest you to use dynamic strict or false, instead of true. Self generated templates (mapping) sometimes cause problems later on

Comment: This is not bug , it the size of the data type. Float can only store nine values before decimal point and double is a larger type

Answer (score 0):

As [@jaspreet-chahal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9279354/jaspreet-chahal) correctly mentioned, this is *not* a bug.

The `float` [numeric field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html#number) in elasticsearch follows the [IEEE 754 standard](https://standards.ieee.org/standard/754-2019.html)([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)) for a [single-precision floating point floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), restricted to finite values (i.e. not Infinite nor `NaN` see [@elastic/elasticsearch#27653](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/27653)).

For example:

The equivalent float of `1571760898.821922` is `1571760896`, hence the error in your scripted field.

[image: IEEE754 converter]

https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

---

Please mark [jaspreet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58552219/6943587) as the accepted solution. Thanks